# Unrecognized dependency in gradle build for slib-dist-0.9-all-jar

Tags: android, jar, android-gradle-plugin, pom.xml, semantics

I want to use "slib-dist-0.9-all-jar" for my android project.

I downloaded the jar from [semantics measure library](http://www.semantic-measures-library.org/sml/?q=downloads) and copied it in my android project/apps/libs folder. and in gradle , added a line as "compile files('libs/slib-dist-0.9-all-jar')" but it says that it is not a jar file . I also tried directly giving gradle build with
`compile group: 'com.github.sharispe', name: 'slib-sml', version: '0.9.1'` but in this case also it says

`Unrecognized dependency: 'com.github.sharispe:slib-graph:0.9.1' (type: 'pom', extension: 'pom')`.

Please help is there something i can do to use it as jar file and not pom?

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile files('libs/slib-dist-0.9-all-jar')  //OR THIS
compile group: 'com.github.sharispe', name: 'slib-sml', version: '0.9.1'
}
```

Comment: have you added it as library ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after lots of research and trials I found a solution over this,
Follow this **steps** to add **slib-dist-0.9-all-jar.jar** or **any external jar** file to your android studio project:-

- **Step 1:** copy the jar file and paste it into **Project_Location\app** directory in your project.
- **Step 2:** Goto **Android Studio** -> then click on **file menu** -> Goto **Project Structure** -> Goto **dependencies tab** -> click
  **plus button** to add new dependency -> select **file dependency** -> then select the jar file **(`slib-dist-0.9-all-jar.jar`)** which we copied in the Project_Location/app/ directory -> click **ok** ->
  **`clean and build`** the project
- **Step 3:** dependency will be added automatically in the **gradle file** of project.

Gradle dependencies will be like this :-

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile files('slib-dist-0.9-all-jar.jar')
}
```

Screenshots are given below :-

**Step 1 :-** Copy and Paste jar file
 [image]

**Step 2 :-** Add dependency
[image]

**Step 3 :-** gradle file after clean and build
 [image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i dont think its about adding it as library or importing it as jar.. the gradle is not recognising it as jar coz it looks to be pom

Comment: i get this error : Warning:Project app: Only Jar-type local dependencies are supported. Cannot handle:

Comment: ok. I thought that its a jar. I will give you a solution soon.

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894032/how-to-use-poms-as-a-dependency-in-maven @Jana. Post back if helpful.

Comment: i dont know why the jar file is not present in step 2: add dependency

Comment: have you copied the jar file in app/ directory correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio, please check the accepted answer here: [Android Studio: Add jar as library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library)

The line `compile group: 'com.github.sharispe', name: 'slib-sml', version: '0.9.1'` seems unnecessary (This is used for External respositories like Maven/JCenter etc. Not required for a jar file).