# Automatically including sub-modules of another maven project

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, package, parent

I have my project structure like this.

```
   pro
     pro-common
       pom.xml
     pro-list-history  ==> [1] Packaging type pom
        pro-list-main    
           pro-list-entities
              pom.xml
           pro-list-daos
               pom.xml
           pro-list-services
              pom.xml
        pom.xml
     pro-search
        pom.xml
     pro-customers
        pom.xml
   pom.xml


 pro2
     pro-list-history
        pro-list-main    
           pro-list-entities
              pom.xml
           pro-list-daos
               pom.xml
           pro-list-services
              pom.xml    ==> Want to use [1]
        pom.xml
     pom.xml
```

My question is is okay to use groupId and artifactID from [1] in the second project as shown above?
The referred module packaging type is pom.

Put a dependency section in the project two at the specified module as shown above, and specified  as pom. Build is fine, but its not importing the dependencies from that project.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Use one library in another project? Have a common parent pom?

Comment: Question is adding a reference to a POM package module as a dependency in a project.  Yes, I need to include libraries from the other pojrect, which has parent packageed as pom.

Comment: You will need to run `mvn install` and/or `mvn deploy` project 1 so that you can use its libraries in project 2.

Comment: I did that. But since the other project I am referring to is a pom type, its not including the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can depend on a POM dependency. See: [Netbeans: maven dependencies of type pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868537/netbeans-maven-dependencies-of-type-pom) for an example and discussion.

However, I think you are asking if there is a short-hand way to import all the sub-modules of a "parent" module by specifying its pom.If so, see this question:
[Maven - include all submodules of a pom as dependencies in another module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848979/maven-include-all-submodules-of-a-pom-as-dependencies-in-another-module)

Answer (score 1):

You can just reference the sub-module in another module like you would a file:

```
<modules>
    <module>inside-project-module</module>
    <module>inside-project-module</module>
    <module>inside-project-module</module>
    <module>../OtherProject/outside-project-module</module>
<modules>
```